# My slide show option in power point isn't working on my macbook

Tags: macos, ms-office, slideshow

I am trying to use slide show option for my PowerPoint presentation on my MacBook. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) Unfortunately, your question doesn't really provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to add info such as what you've already tried? And, what actually *happens* when you try? Also, what version of MS PowerPoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Press up arrow, command and enter for the slide show from beginning
Press command and enter from the current slide.

If is not working again then uninstall powerpoint by using "Appdelete" or "CleanMyMacX" then reinstall again.